# how to make custom datetimepicker using mask edit textbox in c# winform

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

How to make a custom date time picker control using mask edit textbox in C# WinForm. By default it should display the text `'MM/DD/YYYY'` and after clicking on it, it should show the mask edit `TextBox`.

Comment: Overlap the textbox with a Label.  Hide it when it is clicked and set the focus to the textbox.  Unhide it on the Leave event.

Comment: You can 'MM/DD/YYYY'as tool tip for that control

Answer (score 0):

you can show a example by using below code snippet 
in the **designer.cs** add following lines

```
        this.maskedTextBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(29, 251);
        this.maskedTextBox1.Mask = "00/00/0000";
        this.maskedTextBox1.Name = "maskedTextBox1";
        this.maskedTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
        this.maskedTextBox1.TabIndex = 10;
        this.maskedTextBox1.Text = "31071770";
        this.maskedTextBox1.TextMaskFormat = System.Windows.Forms.MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals;
        this.maskedTextBox1.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.maskedTextBox1_Enter);
        this.maskedTextBox1.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.maskedTextBox1_Leave);
```

and in the **code.cs** add these functions

```
        private void maskedTextBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (maskedTextBox1.Text == "31071770")
        {
            maskedTextBox1.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private void maskedTextBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (maskedTextBox1.Text == "")
        {
            maskedTextBox1.Text = "31071770";
        }
    }
```

o/p
**31/07/1970**

**Note :** At last you have to validate that date